# Registering Changed Input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, textbox, telerik

So I am working on a webpage that displays stored information in a form that can be edited. Basically a Requester can enter their contact information which is stored in a database and than can be called by an "editor" who will look over their information and update the request. The issue that I am having is that when I initially populate the form it is setting the value of each textbox to an input and I want to be able to get the changed input in each form to update the database. 
This is the code I use to populate the form:

```
Dim CustomerName As TextBox = DirectCast(RadPanelBar1.FindItemByValue("RequesterInformation").FindControl("txtCustomerName"), TextBox)
        CustomerName.Text() = PMPMR.CustomerName
```

This is the code I use to get the updated information from the form once the editor clicks the approve button:

```
Dim CustomerName As TextBox = DirectCast(RadPanelBar1.FindItemByValue("RequesterInformation").FindControl("txtCustomerName"), TextBox)
        Information.CustomerName = CustomerName.Text
```

I realize this is a very small sample to show but the code for this webpage is over 800 lines. Thank you!